# ES6 array destruction with multiple arguments inside for-of loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can you explain how array destruction with multiple arguments works inside for-of loop when iterating over array?

for one argument, x, I get the following (reasonable) iteration behaviour:

```
for(let [ x ] of ["1", "2", "3"]) {
  console.log(`x=${x}`);
}

output:
x=1
x=2
x=3
```

but i can't figure how to iterate correctly with two arguments, x and y.
tried:

```
for(let [ x , y ] of ["1", "2", "3"]) {
  console.log(`x=${x}`);
  console.log(`y=${y}`);
}

output:
x=1
y=undefined
x=2
y=undefined
x=3
y=undefined
```

and:

```
for(let [ x , y ] of [["1", "2", "3"]]){
  console.log(`x=${x}`);
  console.log(`y=${y}`);
}
```

or -

```
for(let [ x , y ] of [["1", "2", "3", "4"]]){
      console.log(`x=${x}`);
      console.log(`y=${y}`);
    }

which both output:
x=1
y=2
```

why doesn't x,y continue to iterate over the array, so they will get values 3, 4?

**UPDATE:**

got to struggle with it when trying 'array destructing' kata from http://es6katas.org/.

the last test in [there](http://tddbin.com/#?kata=es6/language/destructuring/array) is to make this pass:

```
  it('in for-of loop', () => {
    for (var [a, b] of [[0, 1, 2]]) {}
    assert.deepEqual([a, b], [1, 2]);
  });
```

Comment: `x` is `"1"` because the first character in the string is `1`. `y` is `undefined` because there is no second character in the string.

Comment: You can try `for [x, y] of ["12", "345"]` or `for [x, y] of [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this example:

```
for(let [x, y] of ["1", "2", "3"]) {
  console.log(`x=${x}`);
  console.log(`y=${y}`);
}
```

you iterate over an array of strings, with 3 values, but you try to unpack each value to 2 variables. so the first one get initiated with the value, and the second one with `undefined`.

in this example:

```
for(let [x, y] of [["1", "2", "3", "4"]]){
      console.log(`x=${x}`);
      console.log(`y=${y}`);
    }
```

you iterate over an array of arrays, but you only have 1 internal array.
so the iterator run only once.
if you had 4 variables, they would get the values `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, `"4"` respectively.
but you gave only 2, so only them get initiated.

you can try this with:

```
for(let [x, y, z, w] of [["1", "2", "3", "4"]]){
      console.log(`x=${x}`);
      console.log(`y=${y}`);
      console.log(`z=${z}`);
      console.log(`w=${w}`);
    }
```

(the example in the middle is exactly like the last one, but with less values in each internal array)

on the other hand, if you had:

```
for(let [x, y] of [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"]]){
      console.log(`x=${x}`);
      console.log(`y=${y}`);
    }
```

you would get:

```
x=1
y=2
x=3
y=4
```

**UPDATE:**
to pass the tests you submitted, you can do:

```
// 10: destructuring - array
// To do: make all tests pass, leave the assert lines unchanged!

describe('destructuring arrays makes shorter code', () => {

  it('extract value from array, e.g. extract 0 into x like so `let [x] = [0];`', () => {
    let [firstValue] = [1]; //enclosed in array
    assert.strictEqual(firstValue, 1);
  });

  it('swap two variables, in one operation', () => {
    let [x, y] = ['ax', 'why'];
    [x, y] = [y, x]; //swapped right side of the assignment
    assert.deepEqual([x, y], ['why', 'ax']);
  });

  it('leading commas', () => {
    const all = ['ax', 'why', 'zet'];
    const [,,z] = all; //added one extra leading comma
    assert.equal(z, 'zet');
  });

  it('extract from nested arrays', () => {
    const user = [['Some', 'One'], 23];
    const [[firstName, surname], age] = user; //enclosed as internal array

    const expected = 'Some One = 23 years';
    assert.equal(`${firstName} ${surname} = ${age} years`, expected);
  });

  it('chained assignments', () => {
    let c, d;
    let [a, b] = [c, d] = [1, 2]; //enclosed a,b as array
    assert.deepEqual([a, b, c, d], [1, 2, 1, 2]);
  });

  it('in for-of loop', () => {
    for (var [, a, b] of [[0, 1, 2]]) {} //added extra comma
    assert.deepEqual([a, b], [1, 2]);
  });
});
```

**It's not the only way to solve this.**

Comment: thanks for the explanation @avrahamcool, can you please review the update to the question and refer to how would you solve it?

Comment: @avivr You should avoid updating your question to ask follow-up questions. Ask a new question if you have another requirement.

Comment: @avivr I updated the answer. but keep in mind that if you read and understood the logic of array destruction, you should be able to solve this by yourself fairly easily.

Comment: Additionally, it's good to know that you can iterate over an array with `for..of` using index and items.
`for(let [index, value] of ["1", "2", "3"].entries(){
        console.log(index); // 0, 1, 2
        console.log(value) // 1, 2, 3
    }`